# Printing int -> int list in ocaml

Tags: list, function, graph, int, ocaml

The function 'succ_di_nodo' prints the successors of a given node in a given graph:

```
type peso = int;;
type 'a grafo = Gr of (int * peso * int) list;;
let g1 =  Gr [(1,3,2);(1,9,5);(2,2,3);(5,4,6);(3,1,6);(3,7,4);(6,2,7);(4,4,6)];;

let rec succ_di_nodo (Gr grafo) nodo =
    let rec f_ausiliaria = function
        [] -> []
        | (x,y,z)::coda -> 
            if x = nodo then z::f_ausiliaria coda
            else if z = nodo then x::f_ausiliaria coda
            else f_ausiliaria coda in f_ausiliaria grafo;;
```

g1 is the Graph itself and the value are (node1,weight,node2).
When i pass to the function succ_di_nodo the value for example (succ_di_nodo g1 4) it returns correctly: int list = [3;6].

The question is, when i call the function (succ_di_nodo g1) without giving a specific node it return the type int -> int list; so it is not an empty list and i want to see the exact return value of this function call. How can i print the type int -> int list in Ocaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `succ_di_nodo` with only one argument it returns a function that accepts the second argument and returns the list of successors. This is called [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).

The `int -> int list` type denotes a function that takes one argument of type `int`  and returns a value of type `int list`. You can't print a function value (the default printer will just print `<fun>`). In order to print a function, you would need to enumerate all values in the input domain, which is usually infinite (or close to that). For testing purposes, you can, of course, apply you function to a set of input values, to see what it outputs, e.g.,

```
List.init 10 (succ_di_nodo g1);;
```

will apply `(succ_di_nodo g1)` to `0`, `1`, and so on up to `9` and return the result in a list, i.e., the output will be

```
[[]; [2; 5]; [1; 3]; [2; 6; 4]; [3; 6]; [1; 6]; [5; 3; 7; 4]; [6]; []; []]
```

You can also trace your function in a toplevel (i.e., when you are running your function in the interpreter), by using the `#trace` directive. It will show the arguments that go into the function and values that go out. For the sake of experiment try this in the toplevel:

```
#trace succ_di_nodo;;
```

(you need to type the leading `#` it is a part of the directive name). When you will apply `succ_di_nodo` to two arguments, you will notice that the function first returns a new function, codenamed `succ_di_nodo*`, which is the result of the application of the first argument, and, finally, the second argument is passed to the returned `succ_di_nodo*` function. This process is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), which is an essential concept in functional programming.

```
# #trace succ_di_nodo;;
succ_di_nodo is now traced.
# succ_di_nodo g1 0;;
succ_di_nodo <--
  Gr
   [(1, 3, 2); (1, 9, 5); (2, 2, 3); (5, 4, 6); (3, 1, 6); (3, 7, 4);
    (6, 2, 7); (4, 4, 6)]
succ_di_nodo --> <fun>
succ_di_nodo* <-- 0
succ_di_nodo* --> []
- : int list = []
#
```

When you are done, you can untrace a function with the `#untrace` directive.

Comment: Thanks you so much, i was finaly able to continue with my project. I have another question at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59693394/ocaml-path-in-a-graph-is-repeated-even-if-this-has-already-been-found can you also help me with that? have a great day!